# Using PHP Imagine to apply a mask

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-imagine

I have the following:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Imagine\Image\Box;
use Imagine\Image\ImageInterface;
use Imagine;

class UploadController extends Controller {

    public function processImage($request) {
        $file = $request->file('file');

        $path = '/images';
        $fileName = 'image.png';

        if ($file) {
            $file->move('../public' . $path, $fileName);
            $gThumb = $this->createThumbnail(219, 300, '../public/images', 'image', 'png', 'thumb', true);
            $pThumb = $this->createThumbnail(300, 300, '../public/images', 'image', 'png', 'pthumb');
            return response()->json([
                'gallery_thumbnail' => $path . '/' . $gThumb,
                'upload_thumbnail' => $path . '/' . $pThumb
            ]);
        }
    }

    function createThumbnail($height, $width, $path, $filename, $extension, $postfix = null, $mask = null)
    {
        $mode = ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_OUTBOUND;
        $size = new Box($width, $height);
        $postfix = $postfix ? $postfix : 'thumb';


        $thumbnail = Imagine::open("{$path}/{$filename}.{$extension}")->thumbnail($size, $mode);
        if ($mask) {
            $mask = Imagine::open('../public/images/masks/bubble-splash.png');
            $thumbnail->applyMask($mask);
        }
        $destination = "{$filename}" . "." . $postfix . "." . "{$extension}";

        $thumbnail->save("{$path}/{$destination}");
        return $destination;
    }
}
```

It saves the images as expected but does not apply the mask to the thumbnail.

Where am I going wrong (I am using Laravel 5)?

---

Also, when the script runs it takes literally about 1 minute to complete, so it's doing something but the images are still outputted with no mask applied.

---

In the end I think I'm going to use these guys `https://www.imgix.com/`

Comment: Stupid question, but are you sure you're passing a truthy value for the `$mask` parameter of `createThumbnail()` ?

Comment: @Ben Yes, if you look above you will see that I pass 'true' as the 7th param, just as a test. Normally this would be a string containing the name of the mask to apply.

Comment: Also, are you sure that relative path is working for you? Wouldn't it be better to have an absolute path, maybe `$mask = Imagine::open(__DIR__ . '/../public/images/masks/bubble-splash.png');`?

Comment: @PedroCordeiro I've confirmed that the paths are fine and the image is being opened, so that isn't the issue.

Comment: That lib lacks docs, lacks comments in the source and the result of applyMask is... perplexing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cs2fc.png

Comment: It looks like it's reversed :s

Answer (score 4):

### Update 2015-08-04 11:32 +0000

Turns out white transparency is the chosen masking logic in Imagine.
https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine/pull/449#issuecomment-127516157

### Original

It is most likely a bug in the Imagine library. I found the following:

> I could not make GD\Image::applyMask() to work as described in Reflection example in http://www.slideshare.net/avalanche123/introduction-toimagine so I made some fixes.
>
> 1. It still supports only RGB palette for mask, but now accounts average between colors.
> 2. It does change image if its transparency is less than 0.5.

From https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine/pull/449

The associated fix not yet committed:
https://github.com/kasuparu/Imagine/commit/66a36652c76f9b5ff640f465d8f970c563841ae6

I tried the fixed code and it seems to work except the mask is (from my perspective) applied backwards, keeping the black parts and discarding the white parts. I commented on this issue in the pull request.

For reference, this is the fix in action:

Using $blackAmount:
[image: php-imagine-applymask-using-blackamount-20150731-1831-gmt]

And my fix of the fix, using $whiteAmount:
[image: php-imagine-applymask-using-whiteamount-20150731-1831-gmt]